# docker - NGINX Proxy + Let's encrypt

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

I'm starting with Docker. On start I want to set up simple server on nginx with proxy and SSL (only local on my machine) so I do somethink like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - /usr/share/nginx/html
    labels:
      - com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true

  nginx-proxy-ssl:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-proxy-ssl
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy

  whoami2:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    container_name: whoami2
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=vertex.local.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=vertex.local.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=contact@vertex.local.com

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: developer
```

On standard HTTP everythink is fine, I'm getting site but Let's Encrypt returns error:

```
 Unable to reach http://vertex.local.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/zr0QPZ53RHLRFKy76GX1NKx3lY4GPIaVorH4PT88_Ew: HTTPConnectionPool(host='vertex.local.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /.well-known/acme-challenge/zr0QPZ53RHLRFKy76GX1NKx3lY4GPIaVorH4PT88_Ew (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff41fd2e550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

So I have question:

- For Docker (even locally) I need to set real existing domain? If is true how should I set up my this domain (on provider site - records, etc.) and on local machine?
  Or how can I set SSL into my containers?

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment instead of an answer because it doesn't really solve your problem of "getting SSL working on local containers". But Let's Encrypt won't really work unless you can expose port 443 from your public IP address and use a real DNS record for that public IP address. Let's Encrypt needs to be able to connect to the DNS name to validate (which is what you are seeing in the error message).

Comment: The error that you are getting includes the error message: "connection refused". Has the nginx-proxy container come up all the way? If not, what is the error message in the `docker logs` that correspond with that container?